# How to generate a Nonce token for iOS client?

Tags: ios, soap, nonce

Is there any way to create a Nonce token in iOS client side using Username and shared secret key as well as password digest. The nonce is required while creating a SOAP based request to one of my apps.

Let me know if you want any further info or details on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just create a random string or a GUID. The `nonce` is just a random number or string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is class that create a `UUID` it's a category on `NSString` :

**NSString+UUID.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (UUID)

+ (NSString *) stringWithUUID;

@end
```

**NSString+UUID.m**

```
#import "NSString+UUID.h"

@implementation NSString (UUID)

+ (NSString *) stringWithUUID {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return (__bridge NSString *)string;
}

@end
```

Comment: If you're using iOS 6, you can simplify this to `NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];`

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for GUID part, I have implemented this before. However I was under the impression a nonce is different than guid. I ll give it a try with guid and will see what pops up.

Comment: @Kumar I've always used a GUID or UUID for the nonce, the key is that the nonce is random and can't easily be guest.

Comment: @rckoenes I tried with the guid, it never worked. The app is connecting to Site catalyst API and needs a nonce and passwordDigest in the request header. When I gone through their documentation, they have mentioned to call md5(rand()) to generate a nonce as part of php implementation.                   https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/how-to-start-with-the-omniture-rest-api-in-php. Here is the link for some more info what they have provided as documentation.

Comment: The UUID is about the same as `md5(rand())`. `rand()` wil generate a random numer which is then hashed as an MD5. UUID should be random engough. but you might need to remove any `-` from the string.

Comment: yeah I have removed hyphen(-) and using the rest of it.